# Problemas con spool en java

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Estoy realizando un proyecto con cuatro aplicaciones de escritorio en `Swing` que se conectan a una base de datos(`Mysql`) que tengo en un servidor.

Al ser tres aplicaciones de escritorio donde tendria que poner la configuracion de spool.Las aplicaciones lo que más van a realizar es `select` a una base  de datos y  `insert` a otra tabla.

Necesito un poco de información acerca de como realizar un spool de conexiones a la base de datos. He realizado cuatro aplicaciones de escritorio que tienen que realizar `select`,`insert` y `update` y para no tener problemas con la conexion estado revisando que se deberia de hacer un spool pero no sabria como seria la mejor manera para que no tengan problemas al trabajar las cuatro aplicaciones de escritorio a la vez.Entiendo que lo mejor seria para no tener problemas de conexion realizar un spool pero al ser aplicaciones de escritorio realizadas con `Swing` no se de que manera podria configurarlo.

Comment: bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. He leído dos veces tu pregunta y la verdad, no me queda claro lo que te da problema o qué es lo que buscas. Te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, y luego editar tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con "spool de conexiones" (y Google tampoco). Quieres decir "pool de conexiones"? De todas maneras, no se entiende para qué. Un pool de conexiones no se usa para "no tener problemas con las conexiones" sino, en ciertos casos, para mejorar el tiempo que lleva obtener conexiones nuevas (tipicamente en aplicaciones web). "lo mejor seria para no tener problemas de conexion realizar un spool " Seria bueno que nos expliques por qué lo crees, o aportes algun enlace a una pagina, así entendemos de qué estás hablando.

Comment: @leonbloy en realidad, puedes utilizar un pool de conexiones de 1 conexión en las aplicaciones de escritorio.

Answer (score -1):

Os cuento un poco lo que voy a realizar y si haria falta el pool de conexiones. Tengo que conectar cuatro aplicaciones de escritorio con una base de datos que constantemente van a utilizar las mismas tablas para realizar select y por otro lado insert.Se deberia de utilizar pool de conexiones o no haria falta por solo ser cuatro aplicaciones, no he utilizado nunca pool de conexiones para aplicaciones de escritorio  y me gustaria saber si en este caso tendria que utilizarlo.Tampoco por otro lado no se donde llevaria la configuracion.

Un saludo y gracias por el interes.

Comment: no respondas si no tienes una solucion a tu problema, debes editar tu pregunta con la información extra que quieras añadir.